# Add info to txt file upon button click ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I would like to store a int value(increases each time button is pressed) into a .txt file for each person.

I am clueless on how to store each individual's button value upon click. This is what i have came up with. Need help in this.

Actual question:
Everybody who votes should be able to see the total number of votes as well as the vote of each candidate. You must use a file to record the vote.

```js
@{

    var dataFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/data.txt");

    string[] votesArr = File.ReadAllText(dataFile).Split(','); // your path
    string toWrite = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < votesArr.Length; i += 2)
    {
        if (votesArr[i].Equals("Harry")) // Equals here is hardcoded, replace with parameter
        {
            votesArr[i + 1] = "" + (Int32.Parse(votesArr[i + 1]) + 1);
        }

        else if (votesArr[i].Equals("John")) // Equals here is hardcoded, replace with parameter
        {
            votesArr[i + 1] = "" + (Int32.Parse(votesArr[i + 1]) + 1);
        }

        else if (votesArr[i].Equals("May")) // Equals here is hardcoded, replace with parameter
        {
            votesArr[i + 1] = "" + (Int32.Parse(votesArr[i + 1]) + 1);
        }
        else if (votesArr[i].Equals("Jane")) // Equals here is hardcoded, replace with parameter
        {
            votesArr[i + 1] = "" + (Int32.Parse(votesArr[i + 1]) + 1);
        }

        toWrite += votesArr[i] + votesArr[i + 1];
    }
    File.WriteAllText(dataFile, toWrite);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Elections</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="1">Harry</p>
    <input id="1" type="submit" value="Vote Harry">

    <p id="2">John</p>
    <input id="2" type="submit" value="Vote John">

    <p id="3">May</p>
    <input id="3" type="submit" value="Vote May">

    <p id="4">Jane</p>
    <input id="4" type="submit" value="Vote Jane">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This feels like homework, if so please review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions for some collective site wisdom

Answer (score 1):

You could use for example a format for the text.

Harry,0,
John,1,
May,2,
Jane,3

Then you can split by comas and the odd values will be the names and the pair will be the votes.

So you can use odd to look for candidate match and then the odd+1 to get the votes value. You need to rewrite this new vote on his position and write the line again.

You need to look for.

```
        string[] votesArr = File.ReadAllText("path").Split(','); // your path
        string toWrite = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < votesArr.Length -2; i += 2)
        {
            if (votesArr[i].Equals("May")) // Equals here is hardcoded, replace with parameter
                votesArr[i + 1] = "" + (Int32.Parse(votesArr[i + 1]) + 1);

            toWrite += votesArr[i] + votesArr[i+1];
        }


        File.WriteAllText("path", toWrite);
```

Comment: i re-edited my post. can u help me to see if it is somewhere along the line?

Comment: If you want to check if the line is empty I think you can save it in astring and checking its length before doing the split.

Comment: i made some more changes. However, when i compile.. it says System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: I updated this line  `for(int i = 0; i < votesArr.Length -2; i += 2)`  This can be the OutOfRangeException cause. If you want, you can share your code to check it better :)